# Why python set() is taking more time to run than HashSet in java?

Tags: python, arrays, time-complexity, hashset

To reduce time complexity of problems like "Longest Consecutive Sequence in an Array" we tend to use HashSet, but when I code it in python using set() {with *.add()* method, and element searching using *"in"* keyword in ~O(1)}, the total run time is longer than Java HashSet. Why?

Comment: Based on exactly what observations?  Is it O(1) in both cases?  They shouldn't be expected to take the *same* time as they are wildly different runtimes with different implementations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python vs. Java performance (runtime speed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044620/python-vs-java-performance-runtime-speed)