# Is this inefficient, slow, or just notoriously difficult?

Tags: python, performance

Consider the following code:

```
# Generates a formula to get x using only y
from __future__ import division
from itertools import *


def f(x, y, ops=("*", "/", "-", "+", ""), infiniteprint=False, debug=False):
    isiterable = hasattr(y, '__iter__')
    if isiterable:
        string = [str(i) for i in y]
    else:
        string = [str(y)]
    inputs = string[:]
    found = False
    while True:
        for i in string:
            try:
                result = eval(i)
            except ZeroDivisionError as e:
                result = ZeroDivisionError
                # Just move on people, nothing to see here.
            except SyntaxError as e:
                result = SyntaxError
                # If you have an iterable with 0 and 8 in it,
                # 08 would cause it to crash, because 08 is not a valid
                # expression
            if result == x:
                if not infiniteprint:
                    return i
                else:
                    print i
        prod = product(string, ops)
        string = []
        for j in prod:
            for h in inputs:
                string.append("".join(j) + h)


# Usage: f(toconstruct,constructfrom)
print f(100000, 10)
for i in range(2, 100):
    print f(1337, i, debug=True)
```

If if you run it, you'll see that it's pretty darn slow. Is this because python is so slow (and would c(++) more suited for the problem), is this just an inefficient way to solve the  problem, or is it just a notoriously difficult problem?
EDIT: I'm trying to find the shortest sum that results in x, using only the digits from y, and the operators *, /, - and +.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @sshashank124 See edit. It was for a challenge on codegolf.SE.com.

Comment: `Is this because python is so slow ` what makes you say that python is slow? In my experience it's rather fast

Comment: http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=java&lang2=python3&data=u64q#faster-programs-approximately

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/672857/is-python-slower-than-java-c

Comment: `eval` is quite slow, obviously.

Comment: Your if/else on `isiterable` is going to leave you with different types for the 2 variables from the 2 different clauses.  `[str(i) for i in y]` is not equivalent to `str(y)` in any scenario, nor is a slice-copy to constructing a list with an iterable as the single element.

Comment: @njzk2 Is there an alternative, suitable for this purpose?

Comment: @SilasRay (I see. However, this does not cause issues, because of how itertools.product works)

Comment: It doesn't cause you problems because your example code doesn't exercise the other code path, and your inputs for `i`/`y` are limited to single digit integers.

Comment: you could use the `operator` module, it contains functions to perform your operations, executing them would be faster than creating a string and evaluating it.

Comment: @njzk2 Yes, I suppose that could work, but how would you keep track of operator order?

Comment: you'd need a tree of evaluation. Or, I suppose a shunting-yard on your string could give you much faster evaluation than using eval

Comment: to answer the original question - i'm not following your algorithm very well, but it's basically a brute force style algorithm, on what is a pretty large space it seems. so it might be quite inefficient.