# How to define a row and a column on N-queen program?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, rows, chess

I have to write a code for the N-queen chess board problem. I understand the theory behind it but dont understand how I should code it. In this exercise 0's represent spaces, and 1's represent queens)

so far I have only written:

```
import numpy as np
board=np.zeros((8,8))
board[0:,0]=1
```

Following this, I want to define what the rows in this board are and what the columns in this board are. So I am able to define collisions between the queens on the board.

Thank you.

Comment: Each row is uniquely defined by an index between 0 and (n - 1), where n is the total number of rows in the board. The same is true for the columns. `board[i, :]` indexes all of the positions along the `i`th row, and `board[:, j]` indexes all of the positions along the `j`th column. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how much I should be helping you (sounds like a homework), but my curiosity was piqued.  So here's a preliminary exploration:

Representing a board as a 8x8 array of 0/1 is easy:

```
In [1783]: B=np.zeros((8,8),int)
```

But since a solution requires 1 queen per row, and only 1 per column, I can represent it as just a permutation of the column numbers.  Looking online I found a solution, which I can enter as:

```
In [1784]: sol1=[2,5,1,6,0,3,7,4]
```

I can map that onto the board with:

```
In [1785]: B[np.arange(8),sol1]=1
In [1786]: B      # easy display
Out[1786]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

How about testing this?  Row and column sums are easy with `numpy`.  For a valid solution these must all be 1:

```
In [1787]: B.sum(axis=0)
Out[1787]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
In [1788]: B.sum(axis=1)
Out[1788]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Diagonals differ in length, but can also be summed

```
In [1789]: np.diag(B,0)
Out[1789]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

and to look at the other diagonals, 'flip' columns:

```
In [1790]: np.diag(B[:,::-1],1)  
Out[1790]: array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

I can generate all diagonals with a list comprehension (not necessarily the fastest way, but easy to test):

```
In [1791]: [np.diag(B,i) for i in range(-7,8)]
Out[1791]: 
[array([0]),
 array([0, 0]),
 array([0, 0, 0]),
 array([1, 0, 0, 0]),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1]),
 array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]),
 array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]),
 array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
 array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0]),
 array([0, 1, 0, 0]),
 array([0, 0, 0]),
 array([0, 0]),
 array([0])]
```

and for the other direction, with sum:

```
In [1792]: [np.diag(B[:,::-1],i).sum() for i in range(-7,8)]
Out[1792]: [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

No diagonal can have a sum >1, but some may be 0.

If the proposed solution is indeed a permutation of `np.arange(8)` then it is guaranteed to satisfy the row and column sum test.  That just leaves the diagonal tests.  The board mapping may be nice for display purposes, but it isn't required to represent the solution.  And it might not be the best way to test the diagonals.

A brute force solution is to generate all permutations, and test each.

```
In [1796]: len(list(itertools.permutations(range(8))))
Out[1796]: 40320
```

There are, of course, smarter ways of generating and test solutions.

A few months ago I worked on a Sudoku puzzle question

[Why is translated Sudoku solver slower than original?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39192878/why-is-translated-sudoku-solver-slower-than-original)

the initial question was whether lists or arrays were a better representation.  But I found, on an AI site, that an efficient, smart solver can be written with a dictionary.

There are quite a number of SO questions tagged Python and involving 8-queens.  Fewer tagged with `numpy` as well.

==========

Your initial setup:

```
board[0:,0]=1
```

would pass the row sum test, fail the column sum test, and pass the diagonals tests.