# Python methods to reduce running times KTNS algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, time

I have been trying to develop an algorithm called keep the tool needed soonest but during the simulations, I have realized that it takes too much time to run.

I want to decrease the running times and checking other previous questions about how to fast python coding [Is Python slower than Java/C#? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/673019/5589589) I have found several solutions, but I don't know how to implement them in my code.

On my computer it takes 0.004999876022338867 seconds, but the main problem is that for the whole program this function is called 13,000 times.

Here I attach my whole code, if you have any suggestion to improve it please don't hesitate to share with me.

```
import sets
import numpy
import copy
import time

J= {1: [6, 7],2: [2, 3], 3: [1, 6, 9], 4: [1, 5, 9], 5: [5, 8, 10], 6: [1, 3, 6, 8], 7: [5, 6, 8, 9], 8: [5, 7, 8], 9: [1, 4, 5, 8], 10: [1, 2, 4, 10]}

def KTNS(sigma=[10, 9, 4, 1, 6, 3, 7, 5, 2, 8], Jobs=J,  m=10 ,capacity=4 ):
    t0=time.time()
    Tools = {}
    Lin={}
    n=len(sigma) 
    for i in range(1,m+1): 
        for e in sigma: 
            if i in Jobs[e]:
                Tools[i]=sets.Set([])

    count = 1
    available_tools=sets.Set()
    for e in sigma:
        for i in Jobs[e]:
            Tools[i].add(count)
            available_tools.add(i)
        count+=1
    Tin=copy.deepcopy(Tools)
    for e in Tin:
        Lin[e]=min(Tin[e])
    count=1
    J = numpy.array([0] *m)
    W = numpy.array([[0] * m] * n)
    while count<=len(sigma):
        for e in Tools:
            if len(available_tools)<capacity:
                reference=len(available_tools)
            else:
                reference=capacity
            while numpy.count_nonzero(J == 1) <reference: 
                min_value = min(Lin.itervalues())
                min_keys = [k for k in Lin if Lin[k] == min_value]
                temp = min_keys[0] #min(Lin, key=Lin.get)
                if min_value>count:
                    if len(min_keys)>=2:
                        if count==1:
                            J[temp - 1] = 1
                            Lin[temp] = '-'
                        else:
                            J0=W[count-2]
                            k=0
                            for elements in min_keys: #tested
                                if numpy.count_nonzero(J == 1) < reference:
                                    if J0[elements-1]==1:
                                        J[elements-1]=1
                                        Lin[elements]='-'
                                        k=1
                                    else:
                                        pass
                                else:
                                    pass
                            if k==0: 
                                J[temp - 1] = 1
                                Lin[temp] = '-'
                    else: 
                        J[temp - 1] = 1
                        Lin[temp] = '-'
                else:
                    J[temp-1]=1
                    Lin[temp] = '-'
            Tin[e].discard(count)
            for element in Tin:
                try:
                    Lin[element] = min(Tin[element])
                except ValueError:
                    Tin[element]=sets.Set([len(sigma)+1])
                    Lin[element]=len(sigma)+1
        W[count-1]=J
        J= numpy.array([0] *m)
        count+=1
    Cost=0
    for e in range(1,len(sigma)):
        temp=W[e]-W[e-1]
        temp[temp < 0] = 0
        Cost+=sum(temp)

    return Cost+capacity,time.time()-t0
```

Comment: Do you seriously expect someone to go over your code, figure out what it does and suggest improvements?

Comment: If you want a full code-review of working code, try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - but read the help centre before posting to make sure your question is on-topic there!

Comment: And a detailed explanation of the algorithm that you're implementing would help, too.

Comment: Multiplying the time by 13,000, I get that the whole process takes 65 seconds.  What is the maximum time it *should* take?  I do agree with Blorgbeard - while many people are incorrectly told to go to codereview, you've got fully functioning code that you want people to look at.  This question would fit well there, just make sure you mention that it's cross-posted here.  (It's not off-topic here, but is likely to be better received there, so I'm not voting to close.)

Comment: You should use better naming conventions for your variables and probably break this function into many smaller functions.  As is, it will take a while to figure out what this code does.

Comment: @zmbq I was only asking for some knowledge because I have tried several functions and they didn't work. I didn't want you to figure out the whole code and fix it, only I wanted to know methods or suggestions. If the properly place is cody review I will post it there, but I thought that here could fit.

Answer (score 0):

One recommendation - try to minimize your use of dictionaries.  It looks like many of your dictionaries could instead be lists.  Dictionary access is much slower than list access in python.

It looks like you could simply make Tools, Lin and Tin all be lists, e.g. `Lin = []` instead of `Lin = {}`, and I expect you'll see a drastic improvement in performance.

You know the sizes of your 3 dictionaries, so just initialize them to the size you need.  Create Lin and Tools as follows:

```
Lin = [None] * m+1
Tools = [None] * m+1
Tin = [None] * m+1
```

This will make a list of m+1 elements (which is what you'll get with your loop from 1 through m+1).  Since you're doing 1-based indexing, it leaves an empty place in Lin[0], Tools[0], etc, but you'll then be able to access Lin[1] - Lin[10], as you're currently doing.
Simple example you can try for yourself:

```
python3 -m timeit -s 'foo = [x for x in range(10000)]' 'foo[500]'
```

> 100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0164 usec per loop

```
python3 -m timeit -s 'foo = {x: x for x in range(10000)}' 'foo[500]'
```

> 10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0254 usec per loop

Simply by changing your dictionaries to list, you get almost a 2x improvement.  Your 65 second task would now take about 35 seconds.

By the way, check out the python wiki for [tips on improving speed](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips), including lots of references on how to profile your function.

Comment: And how I can adapt the usage of the dictionaries to the list? Currently, I am using dictionaries because they are pretty simple to access the information and update it. If I use a list and I remove some elements the index will be modified and I won't know. Any idea?

Comment: Remember that lists are also dynamic, and you can `push` to an index, append to the end, and `del` specific indices, though I don't see anywhere in your code that you would need that.  You don't ever add to Lin, Tin, or Tools, though you do add to the set that you put within Tools[i].  Simply create your list.  I put a small tweak in my answer to make that more clear.  Good luck!